# How do I send NDEF message from Android to NFC USB reader

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p

I want to reopen [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747619/how-do-i-push-a-message-from-android-to-a-usb-reader-using-nfc/24801809#24801809) about the possibility to send one NDEF message from Android (using Android Beam) to a PC based nfc reader. Does someone know if i can achieve it?

I need also to know if exist a usb nfc reader with keyboard emulation feature to print received nfc message payload in current focused application (es. Notepad, ecc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. Depending on what NFC reader you are using, you could use either peer-to-peer mode or [inverse reader mode](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6482448) (actually Android HCE mode would also be an option, but you would be limited to only some Android NFC devices and you would need to implement code-parts on both ends). One such reader device is the ACR122U. That's certainly not the best choice when it comes to NFC interface devices for PCs as it has many flaws and there exist several versions with wariyng behavior. Still it is one that's widely used and where several example/libraries exist.

**Peer-to-peer mode**

Android's peer-to-peer mode capabilities are rather limited (you can only transfer a single NDEF message and you can't circumvent the Beam UI). You could use a library like e.g. [nfcpy](http://nfcpy.org/) or [ISMB-SNEP](http://code.google.com/p/ismb-snep-java/) to implement the NFC peer-to-peer stack on the PC-side.

**Inverse reader mode**

In this mode, the Android device would operate in reader/writer mode and the NFC interface device on the PC-side would operate in host card emulation mode. You could use e.g. [libnfc](http://libnfc.org/) to emulate an NFC Forum Type 4 tag with certain NFC interface devices. (See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23197444/2425802) on how to put the ACR122U in HCE mode.)

Comment: This won't work. @Osiride is asking for something that works with a USB keyboard emulating NFC reader, and your solution needs special software.